# Database Adapter not setting schemas in Phalcon

Tags: php, postgresql, phalcon

I'm having a problem with my micro application, I use PostgreSQL as database, but the database adapter I create don't set the schema for the models and I need to do it manually using the models manager, how can I avoid setting the schema manually for every model?

This is how I'm creating the Adapter

```
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Postgresql as DbAdapter;
...

return new DbAdapter(array(
    "host" => $config->database->host,
    "username" => $config->database->username,
    "password" => $config->database->password,
    "dbname" => $config->database->dbname,
    "schema" => $config->database->schema,
));
```

This doesn't work

```
$person = new Person;
$person = $person->findFirst(1);
```

This works:

```
$person = new Person;
$app->modelsManager->setModelSchema($person, 'myschema');
$person = $person->findFirst(1);
```

If I don't set the schema manually then the model object can't find the tables and yes, the schema variable is correctly set.

Also I think Phalcon is always using the public schema instead of the schema I set up.

Thanks

Comment: does $person = Person::findFirst(); work?

Comment: No, I receive this error message everytime:

Table "person" doesn't exist on database when dumping meta-data for Person

Answer (score 2):

add this code to your model:

```
public function initialize() {
     $this->getModelsManager()->setModelSchema($this, 'the_schema_name');
}
```

and now you will never need to set it again. It will be set automatically when you call for a model.

Answer (score 0):

Override getSource() in the model. To override the schema

```
public function getSource() {
    return "my_table_name";
}
```